# join like bigquery

Tags: sql, left-join, google-bigquery

It's my first post in here, so I will try to keep it simple and easy to read.

In `Postgres` I can look for the number of times a string contains another string, in my example, I have a list with sentiments and I'm trying to look for how many times they are mentioned in a forum post title which sits in another table. In `Postgres` I usually do this with `LEFT Join ON` string from `table1 LIKE string from table2`. When I tried to do it in `Bigquery` it doesn't work and I tried with `LIKE`, `CONTAINS` and `REGEXP_MATCH`. These would be the type of query I would like to do.

```
SELECT sentiment_type, count(*) FROM
((SELECT forum, page_link, post_title, user, posted_date, content
  FROM [sandbox:Forum_data.forum_table]) t1
  JOIN [sandbox:Taxonomies.sentiment_taxonomy] t2
  ON lower(post_title) LIKE '%'||lower(sentiment)||'%') a
GROUP BY sentiment_type, sentiment
ORDER BY 3 desc
```

Do you know if this is possible at all in `Bigquery`?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use #StandardSql to join on inequalities https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much guys, indeed I had to use Standard SQL but it doesn't work with large datasets so one of my colleagues helped me find a solution by splitting the string into words. The end result is not perfect but functional and it looks like this:

```
SELECT sentiment_type, SUM(vol) vol FROM
(
SELECT sentiment_type, a.vol vol, a.id id
    FROM (
      SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT SPLIT(content,' ') AS content_ind
             ,Vol
            ,ID
        FROM (SELECT content
                    ,Vol
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY content) ID
                FROM (SELECT LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(content,'%',' '),'!',' '),'"',' '),'?',' '),'.',' '),',',' '),'/',' '),"'",' '),'-',' '),';',' '),':',' '),'(',' '),')',' '),'*',' '),'_',' '),'&',' '),'=',' '),'@',' ')) content
                            ,COUNT(content) vol
                        FROM [sandbox:Forum_data.Expat_forum_data]
                    GROUP BY content)
            ORDER BY 3)
      )     
GROUP BY 1,2,3) a JOIN 
(SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(sentiment)) sentiment, sentiment_type FROM     [sandbox:Taxonomies.sentiment_taxonomy] WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(sentiment)) NOT LIKE '% %') b
ON a.content_ind = b.sentiment
GROUP BY 1,2,3)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The query in [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) would be something like this:

```
SELECT sentiment_type, count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT forum, page_link, post_title, user, posted_date, content
  FROM `sandbox.Forum_data.forum_table`) t1
JOIN `sandbox.Taxonomies.sentiment_taxonomy` t2
ON lower(post_title) LIKE CONCAT('%', lower(sentiment), '%')
GROUP BY sentiment_type, sentiment
ORDER BY 3 desc;
```

Practically speaking a `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` isn't very scalable without an equality condition. Depending on the size of your tables, standard SQL may force you to include an equality as well, e.g. `ON t1.key = t2.key AND lower(post_title) LIKE CONCAT('%', lower(sentiment), '%')` (assuming that such a key exists).

Answer (score 0):

Below should work in Legacy SQL

```
SELECT sentiment_type, sentiment, COUNT(*) as volume
FROM [sandbox:Forum_data.forum_table] t1
CROSS JOIN [sandbox:Taxonomies.sentiment_taxonomy] t2
WHERE LOWER(post_title) LIKE '%' + LOWER(sentiment) + '%'
GROUP BY sentiment_type, sentiment
ORDER BY 3 desc
```